# Angular > left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects

Tags: классы, typescript, angular

[image: angularтекст, выделенный жирным шрифтом]

внутри класса только методы и переменные должны быть??

Answer (score 0):

SetTimeout() должен быть в функции или в одном из жизненных циклов компоненты (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). А внутри класа могуть быть не только методы и переменные, а еще и конструктор.